# Impossibilité de poser une question sur le sujet d'une subordonnée

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, linguistique, interrogative

En français, comme dans d'autres langues, il n'est pas vraiment possible de poser de question portant sur le sujet d'une subordonnée (conjonctive). Par exemple, étant donné la phrase

> Jean a dit que Marie a téléphoné.

il n'y a pas de façon admissible à l'écrit de poser une question portant sur « Marie ». À l'oral, on pourrait dire, en insistant sur « qui »,

> Jean a dit que *qui* a téléphoné ?

mais à l'écrit, on se s'en sort pas :

> *Qui a dit Jean qu'il a téléphoné ?
>
> *Qui Jean a-t-il dit qu'il a téléphoné ?
>
> De qui Jean a-t-il dit qu'il a téléphoné ? *(correct, mais maladroit, et sera encore pire pour une phrase plus complexe)*

Comment s'appelle cette impossibilité ? (Je crois avoir déjà entendu un nom pour ce phénomène, mais je ne parviens pas à m'en souvenir.)

---

*Remarque:* En italien ou en catalan, en revanche, il n'y a pas de problème :

> Chi credi che telefonerà?
>
> Qui creus que telefonarà?

À comparer à :

> *Qui crois-tu que téléphonera ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le déplacement des pronoms interrogatifs est lié à la théorie du mouvement syntaxique. Essentiellement,  cette théorie établit que des [îlots (Angl. *extraction islands*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Extraction_islands) existent depuis lesquels on ne peut pas extraire un élément ou, plus techniquement, que le [déplacement qu-](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9placement_qu-) est soumis à la contraintes sur les îlots. La nature exacte de ces contraintes varie d'une langue à l'autre, mais les langues Indo-Européennes d'Europe partagent plusieurs d'entre elles.

Les relatives qui suivent certains verbes constituent clairement une catégorie d'îlots, mais je ne sais pas de quel type il s'agit ni comment on les appelle en français (si tant est qu'un tel terme existe). Peut-être est-ce ce qu'on appelle en anglais un [non-bridge verb island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Non-bridge-verb_islands) qu'on pourrait peut-être traduire par *îlot de verbe-barrière*.

Pour plus de détails, il faudrait probablement chercher des ouvrages qui traitent de manière technique de l'interrogation ou des contraintes syntactiques en français.

Comment: Merci pour la référence à https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement, dont j'imagine que c'est ce que j'avais en tête.

Comment: Après vérification, un cours de linguistique que j'ai suivi affirmait que l'impossibilité de poser une question sur le sujet d'une relative (phénomène pour lequel il ne propose pas de meilleur nom) est corrélé au *paramètre du sujet nul* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-subject_language ; les langues où le verbe peut se conjuguer sans sujet sont censées permettre ces interrogatives. Ça peut être une autre piste pour avoir des informations sur ce phénomène.

Comment: Dans les exemples donnés il s'agit de subordonnés conjonctives, et pas de relatives.

Answer (score 4):

Mais pourquoi ne pourrait-on pas dire :

> Qui a téléphoné, d'après Jean ?
>
> Jean a dit que quelqu'un a[vait] téléphoné, mais qui ?

Enfin il me semble qu'on peut (à peu près toujours) ruser.

(Quant au nom du phénomène, aucune idée.)

Comment: "d'après Jean" est spécifique à l'exemple de "dire". Je ne vois pas de ruse qui marche en général, par exemple "Jean se demande si Marie a téléphoné", "Jean doute que Marie ait téléphoné", "Jean n'a pas su dire si Marie avait téléphoné"...

Comment: « Qui a(urait) téléphoné, même si Jean se le demande ? » ; « Qui a téléphoné, et Jean en doute ? » ; « De qui Jean ne sait-il pas dire s'il a téléphoné ? » — par ailleurs, « mais qui » marche toujours — et au fond, Jean suis sûr, que Marie a téléphoné.

Comment: Ce que prouvent ces contortions en tout cas, c'est le point initial : c'est bien difficile à interroger ! Question vraiment intéressante...

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question, qui est une question de grammaire.

Answer (score 2):

Grevisse n'en parle pas directement, mais en parlant de la place du mot interrogatif écrit :

> L'interrogatif est en tête de phrase, même quand sa fonction est à l'intérieur d'une proposition conjonctive : QUAND *dis-tu que tu partiras ?* DE QUI *dis-tu que tu es le fils ?* Mais ces phrases sont souvent ambiguës.

Cherchant un peu, je suis tombé sur [cette grammaire en ligne](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page000.html) que je ne connaissais pas et qui a toute une section consacrée à ce qu'ils appellent [l'interrogation profonde](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page509.html).

On y trouve cet exemple

> Qui crois-tu qui a frappé ?

qui ne diffère que par le verbe de mon

> Qui crois-tu qui téléphonera ?

qui ne plait pas à Stéphane.  Mais il n'est pas le seul, l'auteur de la grammaire dit en effet à ce sujet « Selon Le Goffic(1993), cette construction est considérée comme normale par certains locuteurs et mal acceptée (considérée comme artificielle ou obsolète) par d'autres, plus nombreux, qui ne l'emploient jamais ». Je me retrouve dans la minorité.

Sur ce modèle, on aurait donc

> Qui a dit Jean qui a téléphoné ?

qui continue à me sembler boiteux et pour deux raisons.  Passer à l'infinitif et utiliser un pronom de reprise comme dans

> Qui Jean a-t-il dit avoir téléphoné ?

me semble être la meilleure façon d'exprimer cette idée.  Mais ne faire qu'une des transformations, comme dans

> *Qui Jean a-t-il dit qui a téléphoné ?

et

> *Qui a dit Jean avoir téléphoné ?

me semble à chaque fois être incorrect.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, le premier continue à me sembler correct, mais tu n'as pas l'air d'être le seul. Le deuxième était incorrect pour moi et le troisième un reste oublié d'une rédaction antérieure.

Answer (score -1):

On peut très bien dire

> Qui a téléphoné [à Jean] ?

on perd certes la notion que Jean l'a dit précédemment, mais est-ce vraiment important ici ?